# Equivalent condition of the following group presentation to give a group of order $mn$; the other side

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group (not necessary abelian) generated by $a, b$ that has a group presentation: $$\langle a, b \mid a^m = 1, b^n = 1, ba = a^rb\rangle. $$In my question [Equivalent condition of the following group presentation to give a group of order $mn$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3976155/equivalent-condition-of-the-following-group-presentation-to-give-a-group-of-orde) , I was able to understand that if $G$ is of order $mn$ then $r^n = 1 \pmod{m}$. I thought that I have proven the opposite side (if $r^n = 1 \pmod{m}$, then $G$ is of order $mn$), but my proof was erroneous. Especially I'm having a difficulty proving that all $a^xb^y$s are distinct for distinct $(x,y)$s, so that $G$ will have $mn$ distinct elements(I know that all elements in $G$ can be written in the form of $a^xb^y$, because of $ba = a^rb$ and [Prove that the following equality holds in a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3971220/prove-that-the-following-equality-holds-in-a-group)). How can I prove this?

Comment: I gave a pretty complete answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2496975/265452).

Answer (score 2):

$\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$You can do it by *bounding the group from below*.

Construct the semidirect product $S$ of a cyclic group $\Span{\alpha}$ of order $m$ by a group $\Span{\beta}$ of order $n$, with $\beta$ acting on $\Span{\alpha}$ by raising to the $r$-th power. This is a group of order $m n$.

Let $G$ be your group. Now [von Dyck's theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/a/150461/29451) yields that there is a unique homomorphism
\begin{align}
\phi :\ &G \to S
\end{align}
such that $\phi(a) = \alpha$ and $\phi(b) = \beta$, and $\phi$ is clearly surjective. Since the $\alpha^{x} \beta^{y}$ are distinct, for $0 \le x < m$ and $0 \le y < n$, so are the corresponding $a^{x} b^{y}$.

Comment: I'm on an elementary level of abstract algebra, so I've learned about direct product of groups but not about semidirect product. I would appreciate if you explain more about the concept of it. Also, where can I find a proof of von Dyck's theorem?(Is it in the books mentioned in the answers in your link?)

Comment: @Sphere, there is a proof of von Dyck's theorem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013093/von-dycks-theorem-group-theory). As to the semidirect product, it takes me a couple of hours of lectures to go through it - you will find it described in every introductory course in group theory, but please check the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product), which is quite good.